# order-update.js sent "{}" as response in transaction api actions-on-google

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-api, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to send update about order state after a user sent order. I've been using [actions on google transaction guide](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs) codes to build my system. However, I've got "Cannot read property 'JWT' of undefined" error at first and changed my code with `const {google} = require('googleapis');`.

Now, I'm getting "{}" as response on console when run order-update.js file and can't get notification.
I'm trying it on a mobile device. I'm not sure if it is because I'm using it sandbox mode.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const request = require('request');
const {OrderUpdate} = require('actions-on-google');
const key = require('<my_service_account_path>');
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  null,
  key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'],
  null
);

jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  const currentTime = new Date().toISOString();
  const actionOrderId = '<my_order_id>';
  const orderUpdate = new OrderUpdate({
    actionOrderId: actionOrderId,
    orderState: {
      label: 'Order has been delivered!',
      state: 'FULFILLED',
    },
    updateTime: currentTime,
  });


  const bearer = 'Bearer ' + tokens.access_token;
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': bearer,
    },
    body: {
      custom_push_message: {
        order_update: orderUpdate,
      },
      // The line below should be removed for non-sandbox transactions.
      is_in_sandbox: true,
    },
    json: true,
  };


  request.post(options, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(body);
  });
});
```

On guide, I couldn't find any response that I supposed to get but I believe "{}" is not the answer.
For push notification, "200:OK" was the expected response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logging the body (or the error), which is a JSON object. For a successful response, an empty JSON body is not surprising. An error should include an error message.

If you want to verify the response was HTTP code 200, "OK", then you should check the `httpResponse.statusCode`.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay#5_send_order_updates) states

> Some important order updates will result in a push notification being
>   sent to the user's Assistant-enabled mobile devices.

but doesn't say that all will. It isn't clear what it considers "important", however, setting the [`userNotification`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.orderupdate.html#usernotification) field "is a suggestion to notify and is not guaranteed to result in a notification." You can probably add the field with something like

```
  const orderUpdate = new OrderUpdate({
    actionOrderId: actionOrderId,
    orderState: {
      label: 'Order has been delivered!',
      state: 'FULFILLED',
    },
    updateTime: currentTime,
    userNotification: {
      title: "Update on your order",
      text: "Your order has been delivered!"
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, it all worked. Still, I can not get notification but I can see change of state in orders.